# Use of gnome-shell.css and ubuntu.css?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome

Q1. Why are there two `gnome-shell.css` files in Ubuntu 18.04? One is found at `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css` and the other is found inside `/usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource`. Which file does the GDM actually use?

Q2. In Ubuntu 18.04, the GDM uses `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` to design it's appearance. If so, what is the purpose of having the `gnome-shell.css` file?